# DJI Spark: IMUState.Callback.getAccelerometerState() and getGyroscopeState() flipping Sensorstates

Tags: android, dji-sdk

When registering a listener for IMUState callbacks on DJI Spark drones with

```
setIMUStateCallback(@Nullable IMUState.Callback listener);
```

and then evaluating the readouts

```
imuState.getAccelerometerState();
imuState.getGyroscopeState();
```

we get flipping Sensorstates in fast succession (~10ms) for our DJI Spark:

SensorState.NORMAL_BIAS is followed by SensorState.DISCONNECTED.

After ~1s the two events come in again in same succession:
SensorState.NORMAL_BIAS is followed by SensorState.DISCONNECTED

I connected also a Mavic Pro and Phantom 3 Standard, where this behavior did not occur and the IMU reported a steady SensorState.NORMAL_BIAS.

1. Has anyone else noticed this erratic IMU SensorState reporting?
2. Might this be a bug in the DJI Spark firmware?

Answer (score 0):

inside IMUState, there is a index value, which indicates the different IMU sensor, you need check the index when display them, when the index is 0 it means the first IMU (for Spark it only has 1 IMU so the IMU sensor data is included in IMUState with index of 0), 1 means the second IMU and 2 means the third IMU, but the multi-side calibration state only included in IMUState with index of -1. BTW we have fixed some bug in IMU module in 4.8 it will be released soon.

Comment: I checked and yes the IMUState.getIndex() indeed gives different values in a looping event sequence (0,1,-1,0,1,-1,...), even though the SDK documentation explicitly states that the index should start at 0. No more info is provided on this... I assumed the DJI Spark only has one IMU and that these indices are here for drones with more than one IMU? Looks to me still like a bug, as this IMU index is not explanation for the flipping SensorState events nor does it seem to fit the DJI Spark situation, where I would always index 0 for the single available IMU in the Spark.